# Autocomplete jquery UI not working with magnific pop up jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the autocomplete function from the jqueryUI library. I can get this working perfectly fine on a normal page but when I use the same function inside a form displayed on a magnific pop up, it doesn't work at all.

I have added z-index: 9999 on the .ui-autocomplete jquery-ui.css

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The magnific pop up box has a z-index of 1043, 1044, 1045.

With Chrome I have used Inspect Element and changed the opacity of dialog box to 0.5 so I could see if it was rendering behind, but this wasn't the case.

Any ideas what else I may be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please add `JSFiddlee` of your piece of code that will be more helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vybxgpta/ - not sure if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else still needs the answer, you need to add the following code to your webpage to override the jQuery-ui default css in-case you're using Magnific Popup.

```
<style>
.ui-front
{
    z-index: 2000;
}
</style>
```

The reason is because `.ui-front` of jQuery-ui has a `z-index` of 100 whereas Magnific Popup uses as z-index of 1000+ so therefore will technically show behind your popup if on default values.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're not including the necessary `jQuery` and `jQuery UI JS/CSS` files that may be causing the issues.

I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/vybxgpta/1/) , please do have a look.

Comment: I have included and referenced the files because when I use the autocomplete function in another part of the page to test, this works fine. It is only when I try to call the autocomplete function inside the magnific pop up box that it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide me the URL where you're having problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Think there is some conflict with the magnific pop up box jquery?

Comment: Does you `popup` come in an `iframe`  ?

Comment: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ - Not an iframe, it is like a modal pop up box.

Comment: I can't help you with such info, please check browser console and look for the errors.
Or create a `JSfiddle` for this.